# MySQL: unexpected SELECT result after INSERT into table with autoincrement column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm seeing a weird behavior when I INSERT some data into a table and then run a SELECT query on the same table. This table has an auto-increment primary key (uid), and this problem occurs when I try to then select results where 'uid IS NULL'.

I've golfed this down to the following SQL commands:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_users;
CREATE TABLE test_users (uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(20) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO test_users(name) values('foo');
SELECT uid FROM test_users WHERE uid IS NULL;
SELECT uid FROM test_users WHERE uid IS NULL; -- no output from this query
```

I'd expect `SELECT uid FROM test_users WHERE uid IS NULL` to never return anything, but it does, sometimes. Here's what I've found:

- Version of MySQL/MariaDB seems to matter. The machine having this problem is running MySQL 5.1.73 (CentOS 6.5, both 32-bit and 64-bit). My other machine running 5.5.37-MariaDB (Fedora 19, 64-bit). Both running default configs, aside from being configured to use MyISAM tables.
- Only the first SELECT query after the INSERT is affected.
- If I specify a value for uid rather than let it auto-increment, then it's fine.
- If I disconnect and reconnect between the INSERT and SELECT, then I get the expected no results. This is easiest to see in something like Perl where I manage the connection object. I have a test script demonstrating this at https://gist.github.com/avuserow/1c20cc03c007eda43c82

Comment: Does this occur on InnoDB also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is by design.

It's evidently equivalent to `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();` which would also work only from the connection where you just did the insert, exactly as you described.

It's apparently a workaround that you can use in some environments that make it difficult to fetch the last inserted (by your connection) row's auto-increment value in a more conventional way.

To be precise, it's actually the auto_increment value assigned to the *first* row inserted by your connection's *last* insert statement.  That's the same thing when you only inserted one row, but it's not the same thing when you insert multiple rows with a single insert statement.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html

Comment: It's also apparently a session variable in MySQL 5.1, so I have to set it after making a connection. No big deal here, but worth knowing.

Comment: Yes, `@@last_insert_id` is a session variable that's used to store the value that the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function will return.  Presumably, it was done this way to simplify the implementation of playback of binary logs: this session variable is actually writable... though setting it after making a connection or selecting for null from a non-nullable column an unusual to thing to do.  Also, updated the answer to be more precise -- when you insert multiple rows in a single insert statement, it's the first of the assigned auto_increment values that gets stored here.